# AWS Cloudfront creates problems with Structured Data Testing Tool for Recipe Image

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, caching, cdn, structured-data

I've discovered whilst utilising the structured data testing tool that using AWS Cloudfront as a CDN is breaking my recipe image.

The error that is occurring inside the structured data testing tool is this:
*//d1o78ap902v01e.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/ScrollSide.jpg (The value provided for image must be a valid URL.)*

I'm using Wordpress with WP Fastest Cache as the CDN routing. The URL is: [d1o78ap902v01e.cloudfront.net](http://d1o78ap902v01e.cloudfront.net)

I can see in the image tag, that there is a double "//" in the src url.

```html
<img src="//d1o78ap902v01e.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/ScrollSide-600x400.jpg" alt="Keto Cinnamon Rolls" title="ScrollSide" class="wpurp-recipe-image" style="margin:0 auto !important;margin-bottom:0px !important;width:100% !important;height:100% !important;max-width:180px !important;max-height:180px !important;position:static !important;text-align:inherit !important;vertical-align:inherit !important;">
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Your tool seems broken.  `<img src="//example.com/...">` is a [protocol-relative URL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Protocol-relative_URL).  Although discouraged now, since everything should be using HTTPS, it's quite valid.  It tells the browser to load the resource using the same protocol (http/https) as the main document.

Comment: That has totally fixed it! Thankyou :-)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! Sometimes it just takes writing it out to answer your own questions.

In WP-Fastest-Cache, i had to include https:// in front of d1o78ap902v01e.cloudfront.net in the CDN settings.

This has been resolved.